# Erro: MySQL backend does not support timezone-aware datetimes when USE_TZ is False

Tags: python, api, timezone, django-1.8

Estou com um problema na api do pagseguro, estou usando o django 1.8 quando tento enviar um pagamento ele apresenta o erro "MySQL backend does not support timezone-aware datetimes when USE_TZ is False."

Não posso mudar a configuração do USE_TZ pra True, porque ira interferir em outras parte da aplicação.
Já alterei onde estava usando o timezone.now() para datetime.now() e mesmo assim ainda perciste esse erro alguem tem alguam solução pra isso ?

Segue o codigo de como esta a função da api:

```
def checkout(self):
    self.build_params()
    headers = {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    }
    response = requests.post(
        self.checkout_url, self.params, headers=headers
    )

    data = {}

    if response.status_code == 200:
        root = xmltodict.parse(response.text)
        data = {
            'code': root['checkout']['code'],
            'status_code': response.status_code,
            'date': parse(root['checkout']['date']),
            'redirect_url': '{0}?code={1}'.format(
                self.redirect_url, root['checkout']['code']
            ),
            'success': True
        }
        checkout_realizado_com_sucesso.send(
            sender=self, data=data
        )
    else:
        data = {
            'status_code': response.status_code,
            'message': response.text,
            'success': False,
            'date': datetime.datetime.now()
        }
        checkout_realizado_com_erro.send(
            sender=self, data=data
        )

    checkout_realizado.send(
        sender=self, data=data
    )
    return data
```

Comment: no setting do projeto alterou de USE_TZ = True  para USE_TZ = False , esse USE_TZ  usa o padrão de horario definido pelo TIME_ZONE  que no django fica no padrão grigo, para alterar para o br  TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'  .. tentai ai o que mencionei caso não de em nada informa o resultado.

Comment: Opa, então no caso já está com o TIME_ZONE de são paulo, o negocio e que se usar o USE_TZ, todos os lugares que usam o datetime para de funcionar. ai a solução que eu achei temporoaria mente foi remover essa validação do app do mysql mais não acho que seja a melhro forma .

Comment: Acho que se trata nem ta no djangozinho esta no teu banco o mysql deve estar em outro time zone impropositalmente quando o projeto esta no horario br e o banco no  padrão da essa inconsistencia e essa demora para finalizar o projeto.. acho que a pergunta seria para o mysql, ve ai se o time zone a maneira que o mysql esta lidando com os horarios esta no padrao.